# linux dd reading file is inconsistent with dd reading mmc

Tags: linux, caching, buffer

Here are my operations：

1. create a file (this file is located in /dev/mmcblk0p8) and input some unique characters

```
vi /userdata/test
lmk743
```

2.sync
3.use xxd to read the content of /dev/mmcblk0p8 and filter `lmk743`

```
# xxd /dev/mmcblk0p8 | grep lmk743
00954000: 6c6d 6b37 3433 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000  lmk743..........
```

4.modify /userdata/test

```
vi /userdata/test
kukuka097
```

5.sync
6.use dd read the content at position 0x00954000 of /dev/mmcblk0p8 without `direct` flag

```
# dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p8 skip=9552 count=1 bs=1024
lmk743
```

7.use dd read the content at position 0x00954000 of /dev/mmcblk0p8 with `direct` flag

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p8 skip=9552 count=1 bs=1024 iflag=direct
kukuka097
```

My question is: Why is the inconsistency between reading file content through the /userdata/test and reading file content through the /dev/mmcblk0p8 ?

I think this issue is related to page cache,but i'm not sure.

Comment: `sync` affects filesystem buffers but not block device buffers. Block devices have own  bufferization layer.

Comment: Linux has unified cache, so disk cache is file cache. What probably happened is flush in between first and second read.

Comment: @stark OP run `sync` before first read so buffer should be flushed. My guess is read bufferization in mmcblk. However, buffer should be invalided after sync. Indeed, it looks strange.

Comment: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_cache` will solve this problem